# How to invoke power query from DAX

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have power query M code that generates the table from JSON input, I am able to load to the DAX using close and apply but I need a way to programmatically load the result set from power query to DAX.

Where can I start?

### Edit

Data in power query window:

[image]

Using below controls I load the data into DAX (here DAX means load to power pivot data model) or Excel sheet.

[image]

Everything looks fine here when I used the Excel/power query controls to load data.

My question here is instead of using Close/Load (Second image) is their any way using code to pull data out of power query.

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking. What do you mean by "load to the DAX"? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: There needs to be more detail around your question, as its not making sense.  Could you provide a small example or an explanation of problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: It strikes me that despite your introductory message, this question _could_ be made on-topic. However it needs more work to make it clear.

Comment: @halfer I need help on this but struck in some other priority work, so couldn't reply on it. I will be always signed into SO will be browsing topics/questions every day. will edit now.